# Design bug: Comment section

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Highlighted name (original post author) laps descenders on previous line.

Screencap taken from Scott's bug report regarding uploads.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This issue is now fixed. The change will be on live after the next production build.